# Hide DIV sections on mobile and Google search and translate

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I am trying to convert my site to mobile friendly.  The easiest way I believe is to hide certain sections when in mobile view and just show the MAIN CONTENT.  The site is general divided up like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="header_holder">
    HEADER CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="side">
       <cfinclude template="menu.cfm">
       <div class="sidebot">Title 1</div>
       <div class="space10">image 1</div>
       <div class="space10">image 2</div>
       <div class="space10">image 3</div>
       <div class="sidebot">Title 2</div>
       <div class="lineG2"></div>
       <div class="sidebot">Title 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="cLeft">
         MAIN CONTENT 
        </div>
        <div class="cRight">
            right content 1
            right content 2
            <cfinclude template="ads.cfm">
        </div>       
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
     footer content
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.main{width:960px;margin:0 auto;overflow:hidden;zoom:1}
.side{
    float:left;
    width:110px;
    margin-right:10px;
    }
.sidebot{float:left;width:110px;padding-top:20px;font-weight:bold;}
.content{width:840px;float:left}
.content .cLeft{float:left;width:530px;margin-right:10px;}
.content .cRight{float:left;width:300px;margin-bottom:10px;}
.lineGrey {
border-top: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
list-style-type: none;
padding:20px 0px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 220px;
}
.space10{float:left;margin-top:10px;}
```

I want to hide the left side ("side") and right side ("cRight") leaving the MAIN CONTENT intact when in mobile view.  According to instructions I am supposed to be able to do so by using @media for example like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 530px) {
.side{
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    display: none; 
    float:left;
    width:110px;
    margin-right:10px;
    }
}
```

Well, it does hide the "side" in mobile mode i.e. when it is less than 530.  However, it messed up the original desktop format.  The "side" menu is displayed properly on the left, but the rest of the "side" content:

```
       <div class="sidebot">Title 1</div>
       <div class="space10">image 1</div>
       <div class="space10">image 2</div>
       <div class="space10">image 3</div>
       <div class="sidebot">Title 2</div>
       <div class="lineG2"></div>
       <div class="sidebot">Title 3</div>
```

went to the top of the left main content "cLeft".  Similar issue with the "cRight" when in desktop mode when I wrap it with:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 530px) {
.content .cRight{
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    display: none; 
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    }
}
```

some of the cRight content

```
            right content 2
            <cfinclude template="ads.cfm">
```

went to the bottom of the left main content "cLeft".  I am at lost as to what happened.  Why would it mess up the desktop mode format?

Q2. If we solve this will this work with older version of CSS?  i.e. in older browser IE 7?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: u can solve it using javascript if u want to support really old browsers, css didnt have media queries back then

Comment: @Iceman  I guess the support would be for older mobile smart phone browsers.  On desktop I don't think old screen is that small so it should never hit that.  I noticed that in general a lot of phone viewport is just 320 -360 so I have to go smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is but if you're trying to get rid of content, cRight and side div , then just paste this code here below your Desktop CSS.

CSS is read by the browser top to bottom so if you add all that other code below your display:none, then you're gonna have some different outcomes than display:none because CSS is read top to bottom.

Hope this helps

```
@media screen and (max-width: 530px) {
.side{
visibility: hidden;
clear: both;

float:left;
width:110px;
margin-right:10px;
display: none; 
}
.content .cRight{
visibility: hidden;
clear: both;

float:left;
width:300px;
margin-bottom:10px;
display: none; 
}
}
```

Comment: This seems to hide it.   Thanks.   Excuse my ignorance, but if this is use for hiding do I even need the float, width, margin-right for the "side" class?   The other question I have is, how is this going to work on older mobile browsers?

Comment: You dont need those other CSS properties.  Regarding which browsers display:none; check out this website http://www.quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html for CSS elements along with www.caniuse.com for html5 elements on different browsers.